# WPF binding to TextBox MinLines MaxLines

Tags: wpf, binding, .net-4.0

I have an wpf `Expander` with templated header. In this template, i have an `TextBox`, which use `Binding` with `Converter` to set `MaxLines` and `MinLines`, which depends on `Expander.IsExpanded`.

The idea is to let user see first line of text and show more when Expander is expanded (alternate solution would be to make that `TextBox.Visiblitity = Collapsed` when expanded and another `TextBox.Visibility = Visible`, but user will lost their cursor position, marked text and i dont know what else)

```
<UserControl>
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
      <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
          <Converters:ExpandedToLineRowsConverter ExpandedLines="5"
                                                  CollapsedLines="1"
                                                  x:Key="ExpandedToLines"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <TextBox MaxLines="{Binding IsExpanded,
                            Converter={StaticResource ExpandedToLines},
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                            AncestorLevel=1,
                                            AncestorType={x:Type Expander}},
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

                 MinLines="{Binding IsExpanded,
                            Converter={StaticResource ExpandedToLines},
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                            AncestorLevel=1,
                                            AncestorType={x:Type Expander}},
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </UserControl.Resources>
  <Expander Header="{Binding}"
            HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}">
      <!-- other wpf controls under expander, they do not affect the problem -->
  </Expander>
</UserControl>
```

`ExpandedToLineRowsConverter` is very simple:

```
public class ExpandedToLineRowsConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public int ExpandedLines { get; set; }
  public int CollapsedLines { get; set; }

  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return (bool)value ? ExpandedLines : CollapsedLines;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    return (int)value != CollapsedLines;
  }
}
```

Problem is, it is working only when expanding, not when collapsing (textbox stay in multiline mode even when `Expander.IsExpanded = false`).

When i set breakpoint in converter, it is returning corect number of lines, but it looks like the TextBox just ignore them.

I have no idea what to do...

**Edit:** [sample VS2012 project with problem](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ub9iky3e3w3ypsg/ExpanderProblem.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Is the textbox height being set at any point?

Comment: @Gusdor No, it is not. Certainly not by me, but pure wpf TextBox have "internal" ScrollBar

Comment: Can you disable vertical scrolling and retest?

Comment: @Gusdor I tried it (`HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"`) but that doesnt help.

Comment: I realsie this take away some of the flexibility of your converter, but is toggling the Multiline property on its own an option?

Comment: @Gusdor Like... Bind `Expander.IsExpanded` somewhere and then toggle `MinLines` `MaxLines` via `TextBox.Name` (variable)? Its pretty complex view/datatemplate (its not only one TextBox in header, it have like 8~10 controls with one homemade just in header and another 20 when expanded -- yes, client want it like that) and i have it in other UserControl, but hey, everything is possible.

Comment: My recommendation is to try binding Textboxbase.Multiline to Expander.IsExpanded and shelve the converter. I'll write an answer when I get home https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.multiline(v=vs.110).aspx imo if you want to add behaviour to a control, you should inherit and extend the control or create a usercontrol with codebehind

Comment: @Gusdor Multiline property is from .net 4.5+, not 4.0 (see tags, i dont edit them) and i have to support Windows XP - client is nonprofit social service (abused children) and they simply dont have money to keep their IT upgraded. Even i work for them "almost for free" (From my side its like donoring blood... I dont do it every day, dont do it for living, but feel happy about it)

Comment: I'm looking at your sample currently and it has a very 'buggy' feel to the problem. I have set `MaxLines` to 10 and never change it and observe Max and Min lines values changing but the textbox height never returns.